# .htaccess redirection with subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a lot of websites that can be reached on subdomains like:

```
website1.com.banana.servers.com
website2.net.apple.servers.com
website3.com.avocado.servers.com
```

I also have domains for every single one of them accordingly:

```
website1.com
website2.net
website3.com
```

What I need to do is just to write a unversal .htaccess rule that would redirect subdomain (that ends with randomWord.servers.com) to a short domain.

For example: `website1.com.banana.servers.com` should become -> `website1.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this I didn't tried it for now,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\/]*)\.([^\/]*)\.([^\/]*)\.([^\/]*)\.com
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: With few minimal changes it worked very very well. Thank you!

Comment: @NeuTronas glad could help, if your changes improve the post you can edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#The line above tells the server to turn on the engine for rewriting urls.    
RewriteEngine On
    #If the host is "sub.domain.com"
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
     #Then rewrite any request to /folder
#This line is a condition for the RewriteRule where We match against the http Host using regex pattern. The condition says that if the host is sub.domain.com then execute the Rule.
     RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /folder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is a .htaccess that navigates through the server configuration within the sub-domain

Comment: subdomain and domain contains EXACTLY same files and my short domains and long subdomains are both redirected to same IP.